# How to web scraping XML page with hidden codes in R?

Tags: xml, r, web

I'm trying web scraping open information (title, author and journal) in ScienceDirect website. There is a problem with the code source because these information are hidden, what has resulted in problems in my code. The function I've created produce a data.frame with one row only. So once I try to produce an excel sheet with these information the result is a long row.

### Necessary packages

> library(bitops) library(RCurl) library(XML) library(RJSONIO) library(devtools) library(RSelenium)

### Accessing the search page remotely

> checkForServer() 
>   startServer()
>   `#Openning the Firefox`
>       `firefox_con <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", 
>                               port = 4444, 
>                               browserName = "firefox")`

```
firefox_con$open() # let this window open
```

### setting the information for the search

```
url <- "http://www.sciencedirect.com"
firefox_con$navigate("http://www.sciencedirect.com")
busca <- firefox_con$findElement(using = "css selector", value = "#qs_all")
Keyword <- busca$sendKeysToElement(list("key word", key="enter"))`>
```

### passing the page source to R

> pagina <- xmlRoot(
>     htmlParse(unlist(firefox_con$getPageSource())
>                  )
>     )

### function used in page source scraping

```
scraper_science <- function(x) {
```

doc <- htmlParse(url, encoding="UTF-8")

tit <- xpathApply(x, "//a[@id]", xmlValue, "id")

class <- xpathApply(x, "//li [@class]", xmlValue, "class")

Inf.Art <- class[seq(59,227,7)]

dat <- data.frame(TITLE=tit, INF=Inf.Art)

}

Comment: This does seem to be a violation of the Science Direct [terms and conditions](http://www.elsevier.com/legal/elsevier-website-terms-and-conditions)

Comment: I'm not trying to get the pdf just the available information (open access). Reading from ScienceDirect: "You may print or download Content from the Site for your own personal, non-commercial, informational or scholarly use, provided that you keep intact all copyright and other proprietary notices."

Comment: I meant this part: "Unless expressly authorized by us, you may not use any robots, spiders, crawlers or other automated downloading programs, algorithms or devices, or any similar or equivalent manual process, to: (i) continuously and automatically search, scrape, extract, deep link or index any Content"

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you for your information. I'll email SD and ask it if I will be able to use this information accordingly to its "Terms and conditions". Thanks again.

Comment: Also check the new [text mining policies](http://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/content-mining-policies).    If your institution has an agreement, you should be able to get XML files using their APIs.

Comment: Thank you Chris. The SD replied my email: "If you would like to purchase something, you have to register as a guest user or you have to be a part of an institution to have full access to ScienceDirect." As I work as my University has free access to SD and I think it is possible to use their APIs.